# Modifying the default type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I'm utilizing generics as below:

```
public override ValidationResult SelfValidate()
{
    return ValidationHelper.Validate<VendorValidator, Vendor>(this);
}
```

However, I can't seem to get the syntax quite right to allow me to pass in a different validator to override the VendorValidator type parameter. I would have expected to be able to use the Type datatype.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do? Do you want to call the Validate method based on a type known only at runtime?

Comment: What's the type of `this`?  I'm guessing `Vendor`... if so then your second generic parameter can be implied, so you don't have to define it explicitly.  Not an answer to your question, but might be helpful to know.

Comment: @Sven - sorta. There's a default type (in this case `VendorValidator`) and I want to override it in some cases.

Comment: @DanPuzey Yes, it's of type `Vendor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a generic type parameter:

```
public override ValidationResult SelfValidate<T>()
{
    return ValidationHelper.Validate<T, Vendor>(this);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
this.selfValidate<VendorValidator>();
```

Note: I see that you're overriding a method. This will not work if you can't change the base method.

Comment: I had to do some refactoring, but this ended up being the solution. It appears I was going down an incorrect path before. Thanks!